# Mapping xml screen to a form

Tags: xml, winforms, user-interface

I need to design a .Net Form for a C# 3.5/winforms application.This form would enable the user to manually enter data and on clicking save button on this form, an xml would be generated with the schema as shown below:

```
<Request ID="1" Type="testType" requestedBy="admin" Date="20081128 19:30:00" date="20100122 00:00:00">
<List>
<Data name="A" date="04/27/2009" region="NA" /> 
  <Data name="B" userName="johnc" /> 
  <Data name="C" date="04/27/2009" region="TR" /> 
  <Data name="D" date="04/27/2009" region="NA" /> 
  <Data name="E" file="C:\Test\ABC.txt" outFile="C:\Test\ABCOut.txt" businessDate="04/27/2009" userName="testuser1"/> 
  <Data name="F" file="C:\Test\EFG.txt" outFile="C:\Test\EFGOut.txt" businessDate="05/21/2009" userName="testuser2"/> 
</List>
</Request>
```

The design of this form should be user-friendly and intuitive as it would be used by Non-IT users as well.

This xml has various data nodes each having different set of attributes.
A data node with the same number of attributes with different values can repeat[for example:data nodes having names "E" and "F"]

Just thinking what would be the best way to have this form design?

Shall I put a dropdown list at the top of the winform, which would show a list of different data node names[A,B.C...]?
And then changing the item in this dropdown list would dynamically change the form below.
For example:Selecting C in the ddList would show textboxes for date and region..and likewise...
Or how to make use of gridview in this case?

Please suggest.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You'll have a hard time doing anything reasonable with this xml.  This has been done before, it is called WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you WinForms of WPF, you should be make it easy to convert DataLayer to xml.

- Get the schema of the xml (xsd one) and using Visual Studio xsd tool, convert it to C# class;
- Then you can design your GUI around DataLayer and when you want to persist(save) you can use XmlSerializer to the work for you.
- That way you will work against DataLayer and dont worry about persistance as it will be based on Xml Schema of your contract/request